# Angular Asynchronous issue when calling service inside for loop

Tags: javascript, angular

How to solve the asynchronous issue when calling the service inside the for loop

```
  let historyMo =[];
    for (let i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
             return  this.userService.getNodes(history[i]).subscribe((result: any) => {

                  historyMo.push(result);
              });

           }
```

Some times it returns empty array value when doing console.log(historyMo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid subscribing to multiple observables in a loop. It will lead to multiple simultaneous subscriptions and potential memory leaks.

Try to instead use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) or [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) functions.

```js
let historyMo =[];
let requests = [];
for (let i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
  requests.push(this.userService.getNodes(history[i]);
}

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.historyMo = response;
    console.log(this.historyMo);
  }
);
```

`forkJoin()` emits only when all the observables complete - makes it ideal for HTTP observables.

`combineLatest()` is used to subscribe to observables that are persistent data streams.

Besides, any statements that directly depend on the `historyMo` variable should be inside the subscription. It's an asynchronous variable and it cannot be accessed synchronously.